# How to make a splash screen in flutter with images and CircularProgressBar()

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create a splash screen in flutter with images and texts and a CircularProgressBar()
I have tried to to show an image its working fine but how to do it with multiple items

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/background" />

<!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />
</item>
</layer-list>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can check the below code. You can change the image what you want to place

```
class WelcomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _selectionScreen();
  }
}

class _selectionScreen extends State<WelcomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
         Container(
           child:  Image.network(
               "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9a/Visual_Studio_Code_1.35_icon.svg/1200px-Visual_Studio_Code_1.35_icon.svg.png"),
           width: 200,
         ),
          // Your asset image or network image here
          Container(
            height: 30,
          ),
          CircularProgressIndicator()
          // Your circular progress bar
        ],
      ),
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Its okay to show splash screen like that but when app starts it show the white screen for few seconds for that time i want to show this widget